Git log -p -- <file> shows a commit with no patch
I asked git to show me all the commits that modified a certain file, and it produced what I asked, except some commits show no modification to said file (and so instead only the commit hash/author/message etc... appears). It seems that most of these commits are merges. What could be the meaning of this ?
Command : git log -p -- <path/to/file>
commit <hashM>
Merge: <hash1> <hash2>
Author: Name <Email>
Date:   <Date>

    Merged with develop.


commit <hashC>
Author: <Name> <Email>
Date:   <Date>

   Modified file to add new header.

diff --git a/<path/to/file.cpp> b/<path/to/file.cpp>
index ece9ea6fc..370c23a50 100644
--- a/<path/to/file.cpp>
+++ b/<path/to/file.cpp>
@@ -1,6 +1,12 @@
 #include "Header.h"

+#include "NewHeader.h"
 #include "StandardHeader.h"
 #include "OtherHeader.h"

Here commit hashM is weird to me, because it appears as an output of the command, yet shows no modification to the file. hashC on the other hand is not strange : it has modifications to the file.

Merge commits (in my experience) would only show changes on a file if there is a manual intervention on a file on that commit (for example, but not restricted to, a conflict).... so I guess it is correct that you got that commit because there are probably changes coming from both branches on that file.

Oh this would be really great indeed !  This means Git knows how to tell changes due to auto-merge (I use KDiff3) apart from manual changes ! Does it also distinguish between semi-automated conflict resolution (e.g. manually choosing revision A's version but not making any actual manual modifications) and fully-automated conflict resolution (KDIff's automated first pass) ? Also, can I use this to tell git to only show me manual changes in a list of commits, including merges ? I can make a different question out of these if needed. First I need confirmation that your analysis is correct.

By default git log does not show diffs on merges, it thinks you're trying to find the origin of some change, not the (possibly quite numerous) merges that just propagated it.
But wanting those diffs is common enough there's a flag for it, a short option: git log -m will do diffs against followed merge parents, so for instance if you want to temporarily treat all merges as squash merges you can do git log -m --first-parent.

Okay thank you. A clarification : "git log -m will do diffs against followed merge parents" in what sense am I telling git log to follow a particular parent, if no further option is given other than -m (and -p of course) ? Will it show the diff against all parents ? Seems yes, from trying it.

And then what is a squash merge, in this context ? If I limit git log's exploration to the first parent, am I not simply ignoring changes coming from other branches ? I tried it, it seems to do that. The diff of a squash merge commit against its single parent would be the same as the combined diffs of a merge commit against each of its parents. Here with --first-parent I just get the partial diff of merge commits to their first parent. Nothing squashy to me.

@Charles re your first, look up history simplification in the git log docs, re your second: you've got it exactly backwards, the differences between a merge and its first parent are exactly the changes introduced by merging the second parent.
